# importing from mysql column to checkbox php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, explode, implode

i am trying to import from mysql column as an exploded values (category id) from table called "products", and print it in a checkbox input, and check if the value (category id) equal to the (category id) in the table called "cats", to set checkbox to "checked", this is my code:

```
   <?php
    for($i2=0;$i2<$rowsZ22;$i2++){
//exploding
    $catszz2 = explode(",", $bussSubcat);
//foreach start
    foreach($catszz2 as $catzz2) {
    if($catzz2==$row22[$i2]["id"]){
    $ischecked2="checked";
    }else{
    $ischecked2="";
    }
    }
//foreach end
    ?>
    <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="getElementById('cats<?=$row22[$i2]["parent"]?>').checked= true;" <?=$ischecked2?> value="<?=$row22[$i2]["id"]?>" name="subcats[]" id="" /> <?=$row22[$i2]["title"]?></li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

the code is checking the last input only (last category)

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You're running a foreach before you actually output the checkbox...

So, the `$isChecked` variable is actually changing in your foreach, but only the last value of the loop will be printed.

You need to move your 
`<li></li>`inside the loop of the `$isChecked`

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but here goes:

```
<?php
for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $rowsZ22; $i2++) {
    $catszz2 = explode(",", $bussSubcat);
    foreach ($catszz2 as $catzz2) {
        if ($catzz2 == $row22[$i2]["id"]) {
            $ischecked2 = "checked";
        } else {
            $ischecked2 = "";
        }
        ?>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   onclick="getElementById('cats<?= $row22[$i2]["parent"] ?>').checked= true;" <?= $ischecked2 ?>
                   value="<?= $row22[$i2]["id"] ?>" name="subcats[]" id=""/> <?= $row22[$i2]["title"] ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```